# What is std::vector::front() used for?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I am wondering what the use of `std::vector::front()` is.

Is there a reason to use e.g. `myvector.front()` rather than `myvector[0]` or `myvector.at(0)`?

Comment: more interesting... why is there a front() when there is already a begin()?

Comment: @Inverse: because the container adaptors `std::queue` and `std::stack` have `front()` but not `begin()`.

Comment: And to be consistent with `back()`, `myvector[myvector.size() - 1]` isn't that straight forward.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Some of the generic algorithms that also work on lists use it.

This is an example of a general principle: if you provide accessors for all the *semantics* you support, not just the *implementation* you support, it is easier to write generically and therefore easier to reuse code.

Comment: Ah, so it is more about consistency with other container classes.
Just out of curiosity: is vector::front() equivalent to [0] or to at(0)?
I mean, what happens if the vector is empty?

Comment: @Tim: Good question. Wikipedia says undefined behavior: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B) and http://fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/stl-containers/sequence-functions.html says the same as [0] which I suppose is also undefined if the vector is empty.

Comment: Looks like my question is completely answered now. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: `at(0)` throws an exception if the vector is empty.

Answer (score 17):

If the type of myvector changes to another data type that is not indexable, such as a list, you will not have to change code that accesses the front of the container.

Comment: Your and the previous poster's answers should be combined.  Abstract concept + concrete example for the win.

Answer (score 6):

Doing this provides something called static polymorphism.

Let's say I've written an algorithm using a queue class.  It has a front() function to get the next element of the queue, and an enqueue() function to add to the end of the queue.  Now let's say I discovered that this queue class is written poorly and very slow, and I'd rather use std::vector which is much faster (I know there's a std::queue, this is just an example).  If the only way to get the first element of a std::vector was with v[0], I'd have to go through my code and replace all my calls to front() with [0].  But by implementing front(), std::vector can now be a drop-in replacement for my queue class.  The only code I have to change is the type of the container in my algorithm.